# is installshield install .net framework internally?

Tags: .net, installshield

I am installing Installshield in my system. I have two questions:

1. Is .net  framework is required for this,if not
2. Does this install .net framework internally?

Because I don't want that after installation it enable .net framework in Environment.

Comment: What exactly are you installing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The InstallShield IDE does not require the .NET Framework, unless you are trying to use some capabilities that it provides. Installations built with InstallShield are similar: unless you're trying to do something with .NET, it is not required. Furthermore, unless you select to include it, it will not be installed.